# SQLITE3 Lock Type for INSERT INTO SELECT WHERE Query

Tags: database, sqlite, locking

### In short:

Will this query install EXCLUSIVE lock on sqlite3 database? In other words - is there a race condition?

```
INSERT INTO reserves (size, owner_id) 
WITH cte as ( 
   SELECT sum(size) total_size FROM ( 
      SELECT size FROM files 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT size FROM reserves 
   ) 
) 
SELECT 10, 'owner-id'
WHERE (select total_size from cte) < 20 OR(select total_size from cte) IS NULL 
;
```

### In detail:

I have two tables of cache entities - files and space reserves. Both of these entity types use some hard drive capacity and this parameter expressed as `size` column. Also, there is some limit of said capacity that I can use. Database accessed from several processes simultaneously, so I must add reserves to database atomically.

I'm using http://cppcms.com/sql/cppdb/ library, which does not support sqlite `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION;` command, so I wrote query above. Will it work as intended?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite will get a SHARED lock when the query begins.
It will get a RESERVED lock before the INSERT actually executes.
It will get an EXCLUSIVE lock when it needs to write the changes to disk, which is usually at the end of the transaction.

Please note that SQLite uses a single, database-wide lock, so all writes are atomic.

Comment: So, it isnt possible to escalate lock to EXCLUSIVE right on start of query without explicit transaction?

Comment: Not without executing BEGIN EXCLUSIVE. [PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) is probably too much.